# How to save the changes after clicking on save button and at same time moving to some particular page

Tags: html

After clicking on the save button , I want that the values I putted should be entered and after this it shoul go to a page that I want.

```
 newbugstring += "<div class='modal-footer'>";
                                    newbugstring += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>";
                                    newbugstring += "<input type='submit' form='newBugForm' class='btn btn-primary'  value='Save' />";
                                    newbugstring += "</div>";
                                    newbugstring += "</form>";
                                    newbugstring += "</div>";
                                    newbugstring += "<div style='clear:both;'></div>";
                                    newbugstring += "</div></div></div>";
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a bit more ?

Comment: use form with action

Comment: Raunak can u please explain,em not getting it